# Join two list and change specific data

Tags: java, list, arraylist

I have next two list, and I need join it in such way that every Person has all Books and makes changes data during join:

**Note:** *How it makes work beyond scope `for() loop`?*

```
List<Person> personList = new ArrayList<>()
personList.add(new Person("John", "Dou"))
personList.add(new Person("Ben", "Gun"))
personList.add(new Person("Andre", "McDonald"))


List<Books> booksList = new ArrayList<>()
booksList.add(new Book("Harry Potter part_1", true)
booksList.add(new Book("Harry Potter part_2",  true)
booksList.add(new Book("Harry Potter part_3",  true)
booksList.add(new Book("Harry Potter part_4",  true)
booksList.add(new Book("Harry Potter part_5",  false)
```

**Conditions:**

Need makes for "John Dou"  all Books are `true`

And for other Person only 3 Books makes `true`

Also have the class `Marker` that contains as Peson as Books:

`new Marker( new Person, new Book, int )`

Here is my code but don't understand. It changes as is:

```
List<Marker> joinList = new ArrayList<>()

for(int i = 0; i<personList.size(); i++) {

    for(int k = 0; k<booksList.size(); k++) {

        If(personList.get(i).getName().equals("John") {

            booksList.get(k).setReading(true);

        } else {

              if(k < 3 && !personList.get(i).getName().equals("John")){

                  booksList.get(k).setReading(true);

              } else {

                     booksList.get(k).setReading(false)
                 }
          }

    joinList.add(new Marker(personList.get(i), booksList.get(k), k))

    }
}
```

**It should work beyond scope  `for()` loop**

```
joinList.forEach( (x) -> 
System.out.println(x.getPerson.getName() + " " + 
                   x.getBook().getName()+" "+
                   x.getBook().getReading() ))
```

But It makes only 3 books `true`

***Current Result:***

*Output*

```
John Dou : Harry Potter part_1", true
John Dou : Harry Potter part_2", true
John Dou : Harry Potter part_3", true
John Dou : Harry Potter part_4", false
John Dou : Harry Potter part_5", false


Ben Gun : "Harry Potter part_1", true
Ben Gun : "Harry Potter part_2", true
Ben Gun : "Harry Potter part_3", true
Ben Gun : "Harry Potter part_4", false
Ben Gun : "Harry Potter part_5", false


Andre McDonald : "Harry Potter part_1", true
Andre McDonald : "Harry Potter part_2", true
Andre McDonald : "Harry Potter part_3", true
Andre McDonald : "Harry Potter part_4", false
Andre McDonald : "Harry Potter part_5", false
```

**==== Expected Result: ====**

*Output*

```
John Dou : Harry Potter part_1", true
John Dou : Harry Potter part_2", true
John Dou : Harry Potter part_3", true
John Dou : Harry Potter part_4", true
John Dou : Harry Potter part_5", true


Ben Gun : "Harry Potter part_1", true
Ben Gun : "Harry Potter part_2", true
Ben Gun : "Harry Potter part_3", true
Ben Gun : "Harry Potter part_4", false
Ben Gun : "Harry Potter part_5", false


Andre McDonald : "Harry Potter part_1", true
Andre McDonald : "Harry Potter part_2", true
Andre McDonald : "Harry Potter part_3", true
Andre McDonald : "Harry Potter part_4", false
Andre McDonald : "Harry Potter part_5", false
```

In future I will use `joinList` in `stream().Collectors` to get next result:

```
John Dou :       "Harry Potter part_1", "Harry Potter part_2", "Harry Potter part_3", "Harry Potter part_4", "Harry Potter part_5"
Ben Gun :        "Harry Potter part_1", "Harry Potter part_2", "Harry Potter part_3"
Andre McDonald : "Harry Potter part_1", "Harry Potter part_2", "Harry Potter part_3"
```

Comment: can you elaborate your requirement? also list of `Books` has to be list of `Book`.

Comment: A book can't be true (whatever that might mean) for a person and false for another. To have that, you need two separate books.

Comment: Yes all instance should be as List

Comment: @JB Nizet "two separate books", what does it mean?

Comment: `new Book("Harry Potter part_1", true)`that's one book. `new Book("Harry Potter part_1", false)`. That's a second book.

Comment: Still can't catch how to resolve

Comment: can you add code where you are getting all books as true>

Comment: @nishant I need to get all books only for one person as for start I have a `bookList`

Comment: What's the issue you are actually facing?

Comment: @nishant makes all books are `true` only for one person, and for any other person, only 3 books as `true` and other 2 books as `false`

Comment: i ran your code you can see here http://tpcg.io/u6KRJ0   it gives correct output

Comment: @nishant I've got it why. If you print joinList over for loop - this will not work.. the propblem still as is. Catn't reach correct data after `for() loop` : check yoursef  `joinList.forEach( (x) -> System.out.print(x.getName() + " " + x.isReading())`

Comment: @nishant so **this code not work properly** over `for() loop`

Comment: you are traversing it wrong way

Comment: use this for (Marker join :joinList){
     System.out.println(join.getBook().getName()+" "+join.getBook().getReading());
}

Comment: see this http://tpcg.io/qxW1Bc

Comment: @nishant Yeah, I meant to use lambda: 

`joinList.forEach((x) -> System.out.println(x.getBook().getName()+" "+x.getBook().getReading()));` 

So have you got that it's not set books true for one person over `for()` loop ? it makes `true` only for 3 books

Comment: What do you want to achieve, could you explain in plain English what the purpose of the code is and what a Book and a Marker object is in this context?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson yes, sure. I did it. _Expected Result_

Comment: Well you can't get the expected result given the current requirement , it's as simple as that. As mentioned earlier in the comments, one instance of a book can have reading either set to true or false but not both. The reading attribute just doesn't belong in the Book class. It could belong in the Marker class but I am not sure what that class is supposed to do.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson thank you, but readiness attribute belong to `Book.class` as _set_as _get_. `Mark.class` just contains two objects as `Person` as `Book`  and nothing more.

Comment: I understand, as you see I have posted a solution based on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to make this work given the current requirements and class design is to let each person have their own copies of the books.

Based on the current code

```
List<Marker> joinList = new ArrayList<>()

for(int i = 0; i<personList.size(); i++) {
    Person person = personList.get(i);
    for(int k = 0; k<booksList.size(); k++) {
        Book book = booksList.get(k);
        Book bookCopy = new Book();
        bookCopy.setName(book.getName);
        if(person.getName().equals("John" || k < 3) {                
            bookCopy.setReading(true);
        } else {
            bookCopy.setReading(false);
        }
        joinList.add(new Marker(person, bookCopy, k)); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Great!  Thank you so much!!